# Selenium Exception : "return not in a function"

Tags: c#, javascript, exception, selenium

I am writing Selenium test scripts in C#.Net and I keep bumping into this exception -

```
ERROR: Threw an exception: return not in function
```

Here is my line of code which throws the error -

```
string code = selenium.GetEval(
   "var win = this.browserbot.getUserWindow(); "+
   "return win.editAreaLoader.GetValue(win.loadedCodeEditorID);"
);
```

Can anyone please suggest why the exception is coming and what could be the best way to get a return value from GetValue javascript function?

Thanks,

Saarthak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [selenium documentation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.ISelenium.GetEval.html) for `GetEval`:

> Gets the result of evaluating the
>   specified JavaScript snippet. The
>   snippet may have multiple lines, but
>   only the result of the last line will
>   be returned.

Therefore you simply need to leave off the `return`:

```
string code = selenium.GetEval(
   "var win = this.browserbot.getUserWindow(); "+
   "win.editAreaLoader.GetValue(win.loadedCodeEditorID);"
);
```

Comment: Got this error - ERROR: Threw an exception: win.editAreaLoader.GetValue is not a function

Comment: its an open source api. The GetEval works fine when I am not returning any value.

Comment: @saarthak - by the sounds of it `GetValue` is `undefined`. Are you sure it's not `getValue`?

Comment: it was getValue instead of GetValue. How stupid of me! Thanks for pointing out.